# Why does woocommerce add to cart not work with my varnish configuration

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, varnish

I have written this Varnish configuration for WordPress with WooCommerce. Caching and backend works, it also works completly when logged in. The only problem i am facing is that add to cart action for not loggedin users is not working and login on my account page is not working. I look forward to your help and say thank you in advance!

```
vcl 4.0;

backend default {
.host = "127.0.0.1";
.port = "8000";
}

sub vcl_recv {

    # pipe on weird http methods
    if (req.method !~ "^GET|HEAD|PUT|POST|TRACE|OPTIONS|DELETE$") {
        return(pipe);
    }

    if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
        return(pass);
    }

    if (req.http.X-Requested-With == "XMLHttpRequest"){
      return (pass);
    }

 if (req.http.Authorization || req.method == "POST") {
 return (pass);
 }

 if (req.url ~ "wp-(login|admin)" || req.url ~ "preview=true") {
 return (pass);
 }

if (req.url ~ "sitemap" || req.url ~ "robots") {
 return (pass);
}

  # Do not cache AJAX requests.
    if (req.http.X-Requested-With == "XMLHttpRequest") {
        return(pass);
    }

  # Woocommerce
    if (req.url ~ "(warenkorb|mein-konto|kasse|produkt)") {
        return (pass);
    }
    
    if ( req.url ~ "\?add-to-cart=" ) {
        return (pass);
    }
    
        # Unset Cookies except for WordPress admin and WooCommerce pages
    if (!(req.url ~ "(wp-login|wp-admin|warenkorb|mein-konto|wc-api*|kasse|addons|logout|lost-password|produkt)")) {
        unset req.http.cookie;
    }

 set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "(^|;\s*)(_[_a-z]+|has_js)=[^;]*", "");

 set req.http.Cookie = regsub(req.http.Cookie, "^;\s*", "");

 set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "__qc.=[^;]+(; )?", "");

 set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "wp-settings-1=[^;]+(; )?", "");

 set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "wp-settings-time-1=[^;]+(; )?", "");

 set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "wordpress_test_cookie=[^;]+(; )?", "");

 if (req.http.cookie ~ "^ *$") {
 unset req.http.cookie;
 }

 if (req.url ~ "\.(css|js|png|gif|jp(e)?g|swf|ico|woff|svg|htm|html)") {
 unset req.http.cookie;
 }

 if (req.http.Cookie ~ "wordpress_" || req.http.Cookie ~ "comment_") {
 return (pass);
 }

 if (!req.http.cookie) {
 unset req.http.cookie;
 }

 if (req.http.Authorization || req.http.Cookie) {
 
 return (pass);
 }

 return (hash);
}


sub vcl_pass {
 return (fetch);
}


sub vcl_hash {
    hash_data(req.url);
    if (req.http.host) {
        hash_data(req.http.host);
    } else {
        hash_data(server.ip);
    }
    return (lookup);
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
 unset beresp.http.Server;
 unset beresp.http.X-Powered-By;

 if (bereq.url ~ "sitemap" || bereq.url ~ "robots") {
 set beresp.uncacheable = true;
 set beresp.ttl = 30s;
 return (deliver);
 }

 if (bereq.url ~ "\.(css|js|png|gif|jp(e?)g)|swf|ico|woff|svg|htm|html") {
 unset beresp.http.cookie;
 set beresp.ttl = 7d;
 
 # Cache-Control and Expires
 set beresp.http.Cache-Control = "public, max-age=604800";
 set beresp.http.Expires = now + beresp.ttl;
 }

 if (bereq.url ~ "wp-(login|admin)" || bereq.url ~ "preview=true") {
 set beresp.uncacheable = true;
 set beresp.ttl = 30s;
 return (deliver);
 }

 if (!(bereq.url ~ "(wp-login|wp-admin|preview=true)")) {
 unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
 }

 if ( bereq.method == "POST" || bereq.http.Authorization ) {
 set beresp.uncacheable = true;
 set beresp.ttl = 120s;
 return (deliver);
 }

 if ( bereq.url ~ "\?s=" ){
 set beresp.uncacheable = true;
 set beresp.ttl = 120s;
 return (deliver);
 }
 
 if ( beresp.status != 200 ) {
 set beresp.uncacheable = true;
 set beresp.ttl = 120s;
 return (deliver);
 }
 
 set beresp.ttl = 1d;
 # The lifetime of the cache after TTL expires
 set beresp.grace = 30s;
 
     if (bereq.url !~ "wp-admin|wp-login|produkt|warenkorb|kasse|mein-konto|/?remove_item=|/?wc-ajax=") {
        unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
    }

 return (deliver);

}

sub vcl_deliver {
        if (req.http.X-Purger) {
                set resp.http.X-Purger = req.http.X-Purger;
        }
}

sub vcl_pipe {
        return (pipe);
}

sub vcl_pass {
        return (fetch);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### First impression

I noticed your VCL configuration diverges quite a bit from the typical VCL examples. That's OK, but it has consequences. Especially in `vcl_backend_response` you've done some customizations that aren't at all common.

First of all I'd like to refer to the built-in VCL for `vcl_backend_response` that you can find on https://github.com/varnishcache/varnish-cache/blob/6.0/bin/varnishd/builtin.vcl#L154-L168.

I understand that the WordPress & WooCommerce logic need to be included there, but your logic seems to lack fallback behavior for the URL paths you didn't cache.

I'm not 100% sure what the *"add to cart"* URL is, but I have a feeling its `Set-Cookie` header is stripped off by your `vcl_backend_response` logic.

### How to fix your issues

If we want to fix the issues you're facing, we can either fix the problem at the root, or we can treat it symptomatically.

Since I don't have the insight into your WooCommerce setup and how it behaves, I suggest we start with a sort of symptomatic treatment.

- Please give me the URL of the "add to cart" logic
- Which cookies does the this shopping cart logic rely on?
- Are there any other endpoints that are used to view and modify the shopping cart?
- Please include an abstract of the `varnishlog -g request` log output. This should be a logging snapshot of the exact moment when the "add to cart" logic fails

> If you want the `varnishlog` output to be more relevant, you can add a URL filter to it.
>
> E.g.: `varnishlog -g request -q "ReqUrl ~ \?add-to-cart="`

Based on the logging output and the answers to the questions, I'll probably be able to spot what's wrong and provide information on how to fix it.

### Longer term solutions

If you're looking for a cleaner, more compact VCL, I would urge you to have a look at https://github.com/varnishcache/varnish-cache/blob/6.0/bin/varnishd/builtin.vcl#L154-L168.

This is this *built-in VCL*. This VCL code is added to whatever VCL subroutine you override. It's important to know that if you don't issue a return statement for certain situations, the built-in VCL will take over behind the scenes.

A lot of the logic in your VCL file mimics this behavior and is not required.

Ultimately I suggest you only extend VCL behavior in your own VCL file for logic that is not part of the built-in VCL. The goal is to reduce the lines of code in `vcl_recv` and `vcl_backend_response`.

That's not a quick fix, but rather a complete overhaul.

Comment: I found the solution to make add to cart working and the rest but still i thank you very much for your answer and you are right that i can further reduce and optimize my configuration. im new to varnish

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the problem. I needed to change this

```
 if (bereq.url !~ "wp-admin|wp-login|/?remove_item=|/?wc-ajax=") {
    unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
}
```

to

```
 if (bereq.url !~ "wp-admin|wp-login|produkt|warenkorb|kasse|mein-konto|/?add-to-cart=|/?remove_item=|/?wc-ajax=") {
    unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
}
```

Comment: Looks good, but don't forget that an application sending a `Set-Cookie` header may also issue a `Cache-control: private, no-cache, no-store` header. I'm not saying that this will affect the behavior of your VCL. If it does, you know what to look for.

Answer (score 0):

The code like:

```
unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
```

is dangerous in itself. While it makes sense to strip *incoming* `Cookie` on some page (and that can be dangerous too), the pages where `Set-Cookie` in WordPress are quite limited in number unless you have a really bad plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. What would you suggest instead?

Comment: Remove any code involving `unset beresp.http.set-cookie;`. If cacheability breaks after this, investigate which plugin unnecessarily sets cookies on every page, and uninstall it.

Comment: Cookies are used by wordpress itself for login and purchase. So i cant deactivate cookies completly

Comment: I didn't say deactivate cookies. In fact, I said the opposite. Remove the code that unsets cookies from your VCL.

Comment: Thanks for this advice. I'm new to varnish and used a varnish template for wordpress. Obviously it was not correct

Comment: You'll want to look at it from two sides, as it is: receiving `Cookie` from client, and `Set-Cookie` from server. My point is about the latter. In WordPress, the `Set-Cookie` is *normally* emitted when POSTing to login form, or adding to cart. *Normally* it is not being sent. Which is why you should not do anything about it in VCL, unless you have a badly designed plugin which sends `Set-Cookie` on every page.

Answer (score 0):

As a result of Mr. Feryn's and Mr. Vershinin's remark i have minimized the configuration a lot without losing functionality as far as I could check until now:

```
   vcl 4.0;

backend default {
.host = "127.0.0.1";
.port = "8000";
}

sub vcl_recv {

    if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
      if (req.url ~ "\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg|swf|flv)$") {
        unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
      } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
        set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
      } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate" &&
        req.http.user-agent !~ "MSIE") {
        set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
      } else {
        unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
      }
    }

 if (req.http.Authorization || req.http.Cookie) {
 
 return (pass);
 }

 return (hash);
}


sub vcl_pass {
 return (fetch);
}


sub vcl_hash {
}

sub vcl_backend_response {

 if (beresp.http.url ~ "\.(jpg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg|swf)$") {
    set beresp.do_gzip = false;
  }
  else {
    set beresp.do_gzip = true;
    set beresp.http.X-Cache = "ZIP";
  }

 if (bereq.url ~ "sitemap" || bereq.url ~ "robots") {
 set beresp.uncacheable = true;
 set beresp.ttl = 30s;
 return (deliver);
 }
 
 set beresp.ttl = 1d;
# The lifetime of the cache after TTL expires
 set beresp.grace = 30s;

 return (deliver);

}

sub vcl_deliver {
return (deliver);
}

sub vcl_pipe {
        return (pipe);
}

sub vcl_pass {
        return (fetch);
}
```

Do you think this is complete or something is missing, wrong or too much?